# How to add multiple new columns to a data frame in R based on 2 other columns in the df

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to add a new column for every 2 columns in my data frame, based on the values of those 2 columns. The data frame has 70 columns and over 60k rows. Here is an small example set with samples as column names (FF1, FFPE1, etc) and genes in the rows:

```
> gene<-c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")
> FF1<-c(10,20,30,40)
> FFPE1<-c(10,9,2,1)
> FF2<-c(0,2,50,60)
> FFPE2<-c(10,10,100,200)
> expression<-data.frame(gene, FF1, FFPE1, FF2, FFPE2)

> expression
   gene FF1 FFPE1 FF2 FFPE2
1 gene1  10    10   0    10
2 gene2  20     9   2    10
3 gene3  30     2  50   100
4 gene4  40     1  60   200
```

I want to evaluate every paired sample. If both values of those samples for that gene are greater than 5, the new column would have a 3 in that spot. If the FF sample was greater than 5 but FFPE wasn't, the new column would get a 1. If the FFPE sample was greater than 5 but the FF sample wasn't, the new column would get a 2. It would look like this:

```
> group1<-c(3,3,1,1)
> group2<-c(2,2,3,3)
> expression<-data.frame(expression, group1, group2)

> expression
   gene FF1 FFPE1 FF2 FFPE2 group1 group2
1 gene1  10    10   0    10      3      2
2 gene2  20     9   2    10      3      2
3 gene3  30     2  50   100      1      3
4 gene4  40     1  60   200      1      3
```

But I wouldn't be adding the new group columns manually.

Any advice on how to do this? I have found similar questions based on multiple conditions but they were only creating 1 new column. Or the reverse and they were creating multiple new columns based on only one column already in the df. I have thought about using `mutate` and `case_when` but I don't know how to do it for every 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For problems like this we can use the 'dplyover' package.
Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer and it is not on CRAN.

One way is to use `dplyover::across2` to select column-pairs to loop over. To select the column pairs we use regex with `matches()`. In the function in `.fns` we use `.x` for the first and `.y` for the second column. Note, the columns have to be in the correct order.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

expression %>% 
  mutate(across2(matches("^[F]+\\d+$"),
                 matches("^[F]+PE\\d+$"),
                 ~ case_when(
                  .x > 5   & .y > 5 ~ 3,
                  !(.x >5 )& .y > 5 ~ 2,
                  .x > 5   & !(.y > 5) ~ 1,
                 ),
                 .names = "{ycol}",
                 .names_fn = ~ gsub("FFPE", "group", .x)
                 )
         )

#>    gene FF1 FFPE1 FF2 FFPE2 group1 group2
#> 1 gene1  10    10   0    10      3      2
#> 2 gene2  20     9   2    10      3      2
#> 3 gene3  30     2  50   100      1      3
#> 4 gene4  40     1  60   200      1      3
```

A more programmatically save way to do the same operation is `dplyover::over()`. Here we loop over a string an construct the column names on the fly, so the order of the columns doesn't matter.

We use `extract_names` to get the ending column digit and then we can construct the column names inside the string of the `.()` function where `{.x}` is evaluated as the current number in the loop.

```r
expression %>% 
  mutate(over(extract_names("\\d+$"), # <- gets us `c("1", "2")`
                 ~ case_when(
                   .("FF{.x}") > 5   & .("FFPE{.x}") > 5 ~ 3,
                   !(.("FF{.x}") >5 )& .("FFPE{.x}") > 5 ~ 2,
                   .("FF{.x}") > 5   & !(.("FFPE{.x}") > 5) ~ 1,
                 ),
                 .names = "group{x}"
  )
  )

#>    gene FF1 FFPE1 FF2 FFPE2 group1 group2
#> 1 gene1  10    10   0    10      3      2
#> 2 gene2  20     9   2    10      3      2
#> 3 gene3  30     2  50   100      1      3
#> 4 gene4  40     1  60   200      1      3
```

Data from OP

```
gene<-c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")
FF1<-c(10,20,30,40)
FFPE1<-c(10,9,2,1)
FF2<-c(0,2,50,60)
FFPE2<-c(10,10,100,200)
expression<-data.frame(gene, FF1, FFPE1, FF2, FFPE2)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I ended up using the second code block you listed because of the way my actual dataframe was structured. It worked really well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- expression %>%
  pivot_longer(cols= -gene, names_to = "sample", values_to = "val") %>%
  separate(sample, into = c("name", "id"), sep = "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "val") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(FF > 5 && FFPE > 5, 3, 
                        ifelse(FF > 5, 1, 2))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "id", values_from = c("FF", "FFPE", "group")) %>%
  dplyr::select(ends_with("1"), ends_with("2"))
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
   FF_1 FFPE_1 group_1  FF_2 FFPE_2 group_2
  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1    10     10       3     0     10       2
2    20      9       3     2     10       2
3    30      2       1    50    100       3
4    40      1       1    60    200       3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just try this:

```
expression$group1 = (expression$FF1>5) + 2*(expression$FFPE1>5)
expression$group2 = (expression$FF2>5) + 2*(expression$FFPE2>5)
```

I would use a similar approach as @asaei. Make it easier for pivot_longer, I changed some names, FF1 to FF_1.....
Difference is the inside of `mutate()`

```
gene <- c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4")
FF_1 <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
FFPE_1 <- c(10, 9, 2, 1)
FF_2 <- c(0, 2, 50, 60)
FFPE_2 <- c(10, 10, 100, 200)
expression <- data.frame(gene, FF_1, FFPE_1, FF_2, FFPE_2)

expression %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -gene,
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>%
  mutate(group = (FF > 5) + 2 * (FFPE > 5)) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = "set",
    values_from = c("FF", "FFPE", "group")
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach:

This splits the data.frame column wise via `split.default` and uses the `apply` function to do some
value matching.

```
cbind(expression, do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(expression[-1], gsub(".+(\\d)", "\\1", names(expression[-1]))), \(x)
       apply(x, 1, \(x) if(all(x > 5)){
         return(3)
       } else if(x[1] > 5 &  x[2] < 5){
         return(1)
       } else if(x[2] > 5 & x[1] < 5){
         return(2)
       })) |> 
  (\(lst) setNames(lst, paste0("group", seq(lst))) )()))
```

```
 gene FF1 FFPE1 FF2 FFPE2 group1 group2
1 gene1  10    10   0    10      3      2
2 gene2  20     9   2    10      3      2
3 gene3  30     2  50   100      1      3
4 gene4  40     1  60   200      1      3
```